# Isn’t ‘I have a pain in the back’ semantically wrong?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I think ‘my back has a pain’ is correct because my back feels a pain, and a pain is a feeling, so it cannot be expressed with locational words such as ‘at’ or ‘in.’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I have a pain in the back" is correct English. It is common for "pain" to be used this way, because a pain is a feeling that can be localised to a particular part of the body. Similarly you can say:

> I have an ache in my leg.
>
> I have an itch on my arm.

and so on.

You can also say "I have a painful back" or "My back hurts" or perhaps most commonly "I have a backache". However "My back has a pain" is understandable but not idiomatic.

Comment: I have satisfaction in my heart with this answer.